# Nested autowire not working in Spring JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am creating a unit test for my Spring MVC `controllerA.` This controller has a service member autowired.

```
@Controller
public class ControllerA { 

  @Autowired
  public Service1 service1;

...
}
```

When I autowire this controller in its unit test. Its member service is null. But the controller itself is wired up.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerATest{

    @Autowired
    public ControllerA controllerA;

    @Test
    public testControllerA {
       //controllerA.service1 is null here
    }

}
```

What could be the cause that controllerA.service1 is not wired up? Since I put `@Autowired` on controllerA, it should wire up its member service1 with an `Service1` bean (it does have an `@service` annotation on its class), right?

The configuration class is the same one as my production context and works fine.

My current work-around is to autowire `service1` separately inside the unit test class. Then assign it to a newly constructed ControllerA object. This way it works.

Comment: Most of the time, when you load the Controller, all the Beans inside it will be loaded too. Can doublecheck your MyConfig.class?! Does it contain the "@ComponentScan(basePackages="abc.xyz")"?!

Comment: can you please share MyConfig class?

Comment: `@Autowired` fields will never be `null` unless you are creating instances yourself. If a dependency cannot be satisfied an exception will be thrown. So I highly doubt the `controllerA` field is actually injected.